# Locked and unlocked movement in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Well, i'm trying to make a virtual assistant with an image i don't know much about tkinter i wonder if there is a way to lock and unlock movement of the assistant.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

main=Tk()
photo=PhotoImage(file='image.PNG')
Label(main,image=photo,bg='grey').pack()
main.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", 'grey')
main.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
main.overrideredirect(1) 
main.mainloop()
```

at the moment I have this but the movement is blocked

Comment: what do You mean by movement? also all Your code seems to do is make an invisible window that is impossible to interact with and what is that image for?

Comment: @Matiiss OP code will show the transparent image without window border.  What OP wants is able to drag/move the image around.

Comment: @acw1668 I got to understand that after I was no longer able to edit the code, already working on a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the movement manually by binding on `<Button-1>` and `<B1-Motion>` events:

```py
from tkinter import *

can_drag = False

def toggle_drag(event):
    global can_drag
    can_drag = not can_drag

def on_click(event):
    global dx, dy
    if can_drag:
        # save the distance between mouse position and the top-left corner of main window
        dx, dy = event.x_root-main.winfo_rootx(), event.y_root-main.winfo_rooty()

def on_drag(event):
    if can_drag:
        # move the main window
        main.geometry(f"+{event.x_root-dx}+{event.y_root-dy}")

main=Tk()
photo=PhotoImage(file='image.PNG')
Label(main,image=photo,bg='grey').pack()
main.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", 'grey')
main.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
main.overrideredirect(1)
main.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
main.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag)
main.bind("<F2>", toggle_drag) # function key to lock and unlock movement
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: a suggestion would be to use a dictionary to store `dx` and `dy` so as to not use `global` (since it is "evil")